# Show list of items not at the show page but at the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

May you help me please..

I have three models:
Day, Course, Dish

```
class Day < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :courses
   has_many :dishes, through: :courses 
end
```

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :day 
  belongs_to :dish 
end
```

```
class Dish < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :courses 
  has_many :days, through: :courses
 end
```

```
class DaysController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_user  

  def index 
    @days = Day.all 
  end
    
  def show 
    @day = Day.find(params[:id])
     @dishes = @day.dishes 
  end

  end
```

View index.html.erb:

```
<div class="days">
   <div class="container"> 
    <% @days.each do |day| %> 
      <button> 
        <%=day.weekday %> 
        <%= link_to "Show menu", day_path(day) %> 
      </button> 
      <% end %> 
    <%= link_to "Back to Profile", profile_dir_path(@user), method: "get" %> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

View show.html.erb:

```
<h2>Menu</h2> 
    <% @dishes.each do |dish| %>  
     <div class="dish">  
       <h3 class="dish-name"><%= dish.name%></h3>
        <h3 class="dish-description"><%= dish.description%> 
          </h3>
     <% end %>
     </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

What do I really need:
I need to display a list of dishes on the index page by clicking on the day button. (When user click on the weekday button he need to see menu list of items (in my implementation dishes))

But as you see I made display dishes on the show page.... May you give a couple of advise how can i realize it?

Comment: You can add a "view dishes" button on the index, next to each day, and a div underneath to load show via ajax. Look up ajax requests in Rails, if you spend some time reading you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try. Is it possible not to make an additional button opposite each day, but use an existing button that I added to the index.html.erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with AJAX request. Here I have added one AJAX request with day button.

```
# app/views/days/index.html.erb

<div class="days">
   <div class="container"> 
    <% @days.each do |day| %> 
      <%= button_to day.weekday, day_path(day), data: { remote: true } %> 
    <% end %> 
    
    <div id="menuList"></div>
    <%= link_to "Back to Profile", profile_dir_path(@user), method: "get" %> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here I am adding one view file for JS request.

```
# app/views/days/show.js.erb

$('.days').find('#menuList').html('<%= j (render "dishes", dishes: @dishes) %>');
```

Here I am adding `_dishes.html.erb` partial for rendering dishes.

```
# app/views/days/_dishes.html.erb

<h2>Menu</h2> 
<%= link_to "Close", "#", id: "closeLink" %>

<% dishes.each do |dish| %>  
  <div class="dish">  
    <h3 class="dish-name"><%= dish.name %></h3>
     <h3 class="dish-description"><%= dish.description %> </h3>
  </div>   
<% end %>

<script>
  $('#closeLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().html("");
  });
</script>
```

Enjoy :-)

Comment: Thank you for your example! I try to write, and write but with some bugs.
And it work fine when i add
`<%= button_to day.weekday, day_path(day), remote: true, method: "get" %>`
instead of your code
`<%= button_to day.weekday, day_path(day), data: { remote: true } %>`
Otherwise I’m going to another page (like {somename/1}) - asynchronous doesn't work
And I don’t understand why your script(closeLink) in _dishes.html.erb doesn’t work properly. When I click Close link I see only white space. I edit it:
`$('#menuList, a').html("<%= j (render "dishes", dishes: @dishes) %>");`

Comment: You can use like: `$(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');`. I think this should work.
Sorry for the inconvenience. I forgot to add `method: "get"`. Use can use like `method: :get`. Thanks. :)